# multiple forms for different instances of the same object class on the same page in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a page with many posts, and each post has a list of comments.  At the end of the list is a form for a user to add a comment.  Only one comment can be submitted at a time.

Can I get away with something like:

```
form for @comment
...
form for @comment
```

or do I need to specifically make sure each form is for a separate object?  ie

```
form for @comment1
...
for for @comment2
```

If it's the latter, how can I make the main page's controller create one comment object for every post on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this on your view

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>

...

  <%= form_for post.comments.build do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :post_id %>
    ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

or, if you use nested resources in you routes

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>

...

  <%= form_for [post, Comment.new] do |f| %>
    ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I used nested resources.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Nested model form](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) for this purpose.